# Limit of sine of an indeterminate function

Tags: calculus, limits

Today I had this problem in a test:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) \\
f(x) = \sin{\frac{\sqrt[5]{(x+4)(x+1)}}{x^{21}}} \\
g(x) = x^{12}
$$

I told my teacher that no calculations need to be done, since the composition is indeterminate in ${0}$. He responded that the compression theorem needed to be used. Does the limit exist or not?

Edit: Using L'Hopital's theorem:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0\, \text{and} \,\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0 \\
\lim_{x \to 0} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$

This is $\frac{0}{0}$, right?

Comment: The limit is $0$ by the [squeeze theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) so your teacher was right.  To see why your statement about indeterminants is incorrect, consider the case where $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=x$.  Then $f(0)g(0)$ is "indeterminant," but the limit is $1$.

Comment: **Hint:** $-1 \leq \sin y \leq 1$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I know about the compression theorem, but if the function's domain does not include 0, what happens?

Comment: A function does not need to exist at a point in order for its *limit* to exist at the point.  The limit captures where the function tends toward *near* the point.  In fact the definition of "limit" explicitly excludes the point where you're taking the limit toward.

Comment: @AntonioVargas So $\text{sin}\,y$ is always between -1 and 1? There is no indetermination? Edit: I understand now. I was thinking that is the function $y$ was indeterminate, the sine didn't make sense.

Comment: @AntonioVargas But what about this? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+to+0+sin%281%2Fx%29 but when multiplied by x, it is zero?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Doesn't the rule say that in order for the limit of $f(x)g(x)$ to exist, the limits must exist independently?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  You're confusing the statement of another rule, which says that IF $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exist, THEN $\lim f(x)g(x) = \Bigl(\lim f(x)\Bigr)\Bigl(\lim g(x)\Bigr)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $-1 \leq \sin y \leq 1$ for any real $y$,

$$
-1 \leq \sin{\frac{\sqrt[5]{(x+4)(x+1)}}{x^{21}}} \leq 1
$$

for any $x \neq 0$.  The quantity $x^{12}$ is always either positive or zero, so we can multiply each part of this inequality by it without changing the direction of the $\leq$ sign.  The result is that

$$
-x^{12} \leq x^{12} \sin{\frac{\sqrt[5]{(x+4)(x+1)}}{x^{21}}} \leq x^{12},
$$

which, as we mentioned before, is true whenever $x$ isn't $0$.  We know that

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x^{12} = 0,
$$

so the limits of the left- and right-hand sides of the inequality are both $0$.  Since $x^{12} \sin{\frac{\sqrt[5]{(x+4)(x+1)}}{x^{21}}}$ is between them, its limit must be $0$ too.  In symbols,

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} x^{12} \sin{\frac{\sqrt[5]{(x+4)(x+1)}}{x^{21}}} = 0.
$$

Here's a plot of just $\sin{\frac{\sqrt[5]{(x+4)(x+1)}}{x^{21}}}$.  Note that it's always between $-1$ and $1$ on the $y$-axis.

[image]

Here's a plot of $x^{12} \sin{\frac{\sqrt[5]{(x+4)(x+1)}}{x^{21}}}$.  Note how it squeezes down to $0$ near $x=0$.  That's what the limit is saying.

[image]

Here's the same plot with the squeeze functions $-x^{12}$ in purple and $x^{12}$ in yellowish.

[image]